# GitPress can not show image

Tags: github

I use [GitPress](https://gitpress.io/) to write blog.

But recently i found it can not show image, but images could be loaded in GitHub.

Here is my [GitPress blog](https://gitpress.io/@wangs/Web%20Scraper%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8)

Here is the opposite [GitHub page](https://github.com/Wangs121/blog/blob/master/Web%20Scraper%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8.md)

I've tried:

- push a test.md, which only show a test image.
- rename the image folders, change the way to show image in Markdown(`./folder/name.png`,`/folder/name.png`,`folder/name.png`).

But the `test.md` sometimes can show image, when i correct the format in my blog, it just won't show any image.

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of GitPress.io.

I saw your posts and found that you have replaced all images with imgur. Please follow [this post](https://gitpress.io/c/helps/faq) if you want to show images from the repo.

Please use the followed structure for your blog:

```
- test.md
- test/
  - image.png
```

and put this in test.md:

```
![](/test/image.png)
```